# How can you know that current request exceeds maxRequestLength in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, maxrequestlength

I'm developing a small web application in ASP.Net (framework version 3.5) using VS2008 and C# 3.0. There's a file upload, and I want to make sure that the whole request doesn't exceed 5 MB.

I configured the web.config file and maxRequestLength is set properly.

I'm overriding the page's OnError method.

However, while investigating the exception, I don't see anything other than string literals and error codes that actually identify the "Maximum request length exceeded" error. All I have is the error code (the actual `HResult`) and the stack trace. It is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded).

This is a bit of a problem, because the implementation of the framework might be different on an OS different than mine: my development machine is Windows Server 2008, and the target machine might be Windows 2000/2003/2008 Server.

In other words, is there a **portable** way to determine current error as "Maximum request length exceeded"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to resort to client side solution with JavaScript or use Flash/Silverlight upload control which also could check the size of the file/files clientside.

Because when you use the builtin ASP.NET's checking it very hard to catch this specific exception. You can, however, display a friendly error page when it happens.

http://www.codeplex.com/SLFileUpload

Comment: This is the closest answer (hence accepted). Actually, although it's a web.config's setting, it's the IIS who raises the exception. That's why we have to use the error codes constants etc. That's very confusing, though.