# IIS 7.0 Custom Error page for error code with a substatus

Tags: iis-7, custom-error-pages

Has anybody successfully created a Custom error page using:

1. The IIS 7.0 GUI
2. a substatus error code (e.g. 404.13).
3. using "Execute a Url on this site" (as opposed to the static File or
   Redirect options)
4. an .asp error page

The only ways I have been able to get my application, which is a legacy classic .asp app, to display a custom 404.13 error message is to either use the redirect option with a static file (.htm) or use the static file option with an htm file from the file system.

Secondary questions:

Is there some restriction is IIS 7 to custom error pages for substatus error codes?

Also, is it ever recommended to return a substatus code because of security concerns?

Comment: Same issue here. Anyone find the answer?

Comment: Complete solution for the 404.13 redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3787284/991267

Answer (score 1):

In the `<httpErrors>` element of `<system.webServer>` you can specify a `subStatusCode` attribute: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors/error

However the ASP.NET configuration elements (children of `<system.web>` do not support sub-status codes.