# maxAllowedContentLength do not work for IHttpHandler IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have ASP.NET IHttpHandler module which handle file uploads. I set file size limit to 50mb in config file

```
  <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security> 
  </system.webServer>
```

But still get error while uploading 13mb file.

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.
```

How to increase default allowed file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following under the  in **web.config** of web application

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="52428800" />
```

Comment: This is actually wrong - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3787284/ - you need kilobytes here.

Comment: Corrrect maxRequestLength is in KB see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

To summarise, to raise the file upload size to 50 MiB in IIS7 add the lines below in the correct section of the Web.config file:

```
  <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security> 
  </system.webServer>
```

and

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
  </system.web>
```

1024 X 1024 X 50 = 5242880 bytes in 50 MiB

1024 X 50 = 51200 KiB in 50 MiB

Answer (score 0):

For classic ASP users also check this settings in addition to the web.config settigns:

IIS **>** CLick on Website **>** ASP **>** Limit Properties **>** Maximum request entity body limit