# File upload size 5 mb

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I am using kendo upload control. Here iam sending the file to controller. From there i am calling web api mentod to save the file in to database. Now my problem is when i upload 3mb file it is uploading. If i want upload more than 3mb file its not uploading. 
My Controller code is like this.

```
byte[] fileData = null;
//Fetches the uploaded file
var httpPostedFileBase = Request.Files[0];
//Reads file data in Binary
if (httpPostedFileBase != null)
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream))
{
     fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(httpPostedFileBase.ContentLength);
}
//Create BO to save file in DB
var postedFileBase = Request.Files[0];
UploadFiles upload=new UploadFiles();
Docs doc = new Docs {ID = Id, Content = fileData};
if (postedFileBase != null) contractDoc.FileName = postedFileBase.FileName;
```

Finally i am calling the webapi call. In webapi i got error.

Comment: You should google it first
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926402/uplaod-image-over-4-mb-using-asp-file-uploader
you can find many posts regarding it

Comment: Have u seen link that i given