# redirect to error on exceeding fileupload size

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I am trying to direct user to a error page when maximum fileupload size excedds.For this iam doing the following thing:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(application_BeginRequest);
    }

    void application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        if (context.Request.ContentLength > 4096000)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
```

But on uploading file with size more than the max filesize it is showing "connection reset" error.
How should i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question: [Display custom error page when file upload exceeds allowed size in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759193/display-custom-error-page-when-file-upload-exceeds-allowed-size-in-asp-net-mvc2/3787284#3787284)

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET runtime might reject the request even before your application fires up. Check the maximum request length set in a web.config - the value should be greater then the one your application is expecting:

IIS6/IIS7 (classic pipeline AND integrated pipeline):

```
<system.web>
  <!-- The value is in KB -->
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
</system.web>
```

IIS7 (integrated pipeline):

```
<system.webServer> 
  <security> 
    <requestFiltering> 
      <!-- The value is in bytes -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this will help.

-- Pavel

Comment: i placed a debugger on  context.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");it is coming to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're probably getting a ThreadAbortException, that's why the connection is reset.

Please refer to this KB article for a workaround:
[ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629).

-- Pavel

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to do this correctly from the handler you will need to read all of the data off of the request before sending the response/redirect.  Alternatively, you can do this from an ISAPI filter and avoid having to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toolkit AsyncFileUpload control and then catch the error in the client side and redirect to the error page.

[AsyncFileUpload: How do I hide the max request length exceeded alert error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426864/asyncfileupload-how-do-i-hide-the-max-request-length-exceeded-alert-error/4094966#4094966)

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUpload" 
                     runat="server" OnClientUploadError="onUploadError"
                     OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
                     OnUploadedComplete="OnUploadComplete" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     function onUploadError()
     {
          //Redirect to error page.
     }

     function uploadComplete()
     {

     }


 </script>
```

Comment: @Niraj: Can you show a alert saying that file uploaded exceeds the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transfer.Redirect()](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Following the [post](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/809909he) the reason can be just a redirection to local site:

> It doesn't seem to work when the
>   server is local (either through using
>   localhost, local ip or
>   http://machinename/). The browser just
>   reacts like the server completely
>   dropped the connection - connection
>   reset by peer / connection was reset
>   (FF) / cannot display web page (IE).