# MVC3:Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

Here is the context:

ASP MVC3 - IIS 7

I am using ElMah configured very well as documented nearly everywhere for MVC.
And it is working.

Here is what I have in my config file

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Generic" />
    ...
     <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" defaultPath="~/Error/Generic" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL"></httpErrors>
```

Now here is my problem
I spent the whole day trying to catch this error : ***"Maximum request length exceeded"*** when I submit a file that exceed 1024 bytes

Between asp errors and IIS errors and sometimes IE interception, I'am getting crazy
I cannot understand why this is so complicated.
I already tried these solutions and none worked for me
[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)
[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When setting maxRequestLength to 1024 this means 1024 kilobytes, not 1024 bytes. Maybe this is why the exception isn't thrown.