# can i redirect from the global.asax to controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

i am trying to show an error page when the user uploads a file that is over the limit (see [Catching "Maximum request length exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded))

in the global.asax i want to redirect to a controller action, so something like thisbut it does not work ?:

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GlobalHelper.IsMaxRequestExceededEexception(this.Server.GetLastError()))
    {
        this.Server.ClearError();
        return RedirectToAction("Home","Errorpage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try like this:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    // TODO: Log the exception or something
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "ErrorPage";
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    IController controller = new HomeController();
    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    controller.Execute(rc);
}
```

Comment: I am using above code in Session_Start(). I am using it while redirecting to authenticationfalure.aspx page when authentication fails. But, the home page along with failure  page both are coming as out put. how to solve this?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov How could I pass parameter to the action method. I want to pass the 'exception' variable somehow.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik, you could trivially easy pass the exception as RouteData value as I illustrated in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5229581/29407

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I will try this. The weird thing about IController.Execute is that it doesn't change the url actually.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for solution . Do we need to define StatusCode ? If we would do that , would we get it on google webmaster tools report ?

Comment: it is possible to add an parameter ?