# elegant maxrequest handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload, maxrequestlength

Another question from me. This wont be an easy one!

I'm having issues with handling a simple upload.
Pre Requirements to test with:
- No Flash (hijacking)
- Basic upload field usage + form to post
- Max file size is 20MB (web.config maxrequestlength)
- I'm running the web site with the build in IIS development tool in visual studio (i think)
- I'm using a MVC web project

Question: Is it possible to show a nice error message to the user when a file is larger than 20MB? (Without getting the whole file to the server first)

These links helped me the most:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/upload/maximum-request-length-exceeded.aspx

[ASP.NET MVC: Handling upload exceeding maxRequestLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952051/asp-net-mvc-handling-upload-exceeding-maxrequestlength)

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/809909

http://forums.asp.net/t/1106579.aspx/1

[Catching "Maximum request length exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded)

But still i haven't been able to fix the issue. Atm i use the code of the accepted answer of the last link ([Catching "Maximum request length exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded)), but my code crashes when i run the code line below:

```
this.Server.Transfer("~/error/UploadTooLarge.aspx");
```

Error message: Error executing child request for ~/error/UploadTooLarge.aspx.

I think i get this message because i'm using VS.NET's build in web server (see: http://forums.asp.net/t/1106579.aspx/1 last post of that page).

I'm affraid i made the whole question a bit hard to read. In short:
How can i show a neat error message when i uploaded file is too large (using S.NET's build in web server)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send to whole file to the server first, then your only option would be javascript.
The FileReader object would solve that for you 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader
Problem being it won't work on older browsers. 
Now, if older browsers are not a problem for you then you should find plenty of tutorials showing you how to use the FileReader object. With it you can do asynchronous uploads so you even add a nice progress bar considering is fairly large file.