# Validating for large files upon Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working with c# MVC 2 and ASP.NET. One of my forms includes a file input field which allows a use to select any file type which will then be converted into a blob and saved into the database. My problem is that whenever a user selects a file that exceeds a certain amoutn of Mb (about 8) I get a page error that says the following:

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

I don't mind that there's an 8Mb limit to the files the users are uploading however I need to stop the current error from happening and display a proper validation message (preferably with the ModelState.AddModelError function). Can anybody help me? I can't seem to 'catch' the error before anything else happens in the page since it's happening before it arrives in the upload function within the controller.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

One possibility is to write a custom validation attribute:

```
public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxFileSize;
    public MaxFileSizeAttribute(int maxFileSize)
    {
        _maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return file.ContentLength <= _maxFileSize;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(_maxFileSize.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then you could have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxFileSize(8 * 1024 * 1024, ErrorMessage = "Maximum allowed file size is {0} bytes")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // validation failed => redisplay the view
            return View(model);
        }

        // the model is valid => we could process the file here
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        model.File.SaveAs(path);

        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.File)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Now of course for this to work you will have to increase the maximum allowed upload file size in web.config to a sufficiently large value:

```
<!-- 1GB (the value is in KB) -->
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

and for IIS7:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <!-- 1GB (the value is in Bytes) -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

We could now bring our custom validation attribute a step further and enable client side validation to avoid wasting bandwidth. Of course verifying the file size before uploading is only possible with [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_files). As a consequence only browsers that support this API will be able to take advantage of it.

So the first step is to make our custom validation attribute implement the [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) interface which will allow us to attach a custom adapter in javascript:

```
public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly int _maxFileSize;
    public MaxFileSizeAttribute(int maxFileSize)
    {
        _maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return file.ContentLength <= _maxFileSize;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return base.FormatErrorMessage(_maxFileSize.ToString());
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(_maxFileSize.ToString()),
            ValidationType = "filesize"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["maxsize"] = _maxFileSize;
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

and all that's left is configure the custom adapter:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'filesize', [ 'maxsize' ], function (options) {
        options.rules['filesize'] = options.params;
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages['filesize'] = options.message;
        }
    }
);

jQuery.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, params) {
    if (element.files.length < 1) {
        // No files selected
        return true;
    }

    if (!element.files || !element.files[0].size) {
        // This browser doesn't support the HTML5 API
        return true;
    }

    return element.files[0].size < params.maxsize;
}, '');
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much Darin. I am attempting to implement your solution however I cannot seem to be able to use 'IClientValidatable'. I have the System.Web.Mvc both added in the references of the project and in the page usings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong. The `IClientValidatable` was added in ASP.NET MVC 3 in the `System.Web.Mvc.dll` assembly inside the  `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

Comment: I verified and I was mistaken into thinking that we were using MVC3, we're in fact using MVC2. Since upgrading isn't an option for me, can any part of this solution still apply?

Comment: @WilliamCalleja, the server side validation solution still applies. As far as client side is concerned, ASP.NET MVC 3 uses the jQuery validate plugin alongside to perform unobtrusive client side validation. In ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2 the default client side validation framework is `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js`. It's a pretty different model. You may take a look at the following post: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Comment: It worked! I wish I could give the answer to two of you but alas I can't, I combined ideas from Darin and Jenea, using the '</system.web>
  <location path="Media/Upload">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="10485760" />
    </system.web>
  </location>'

Comment: Awesome answer! There is one problem, though. MaxFileSizeAttribute.IsValid returns false when the value is null, effectively requiring a file to be uploaded.

Comment: There is one minor bug in your client side javascript validation. The last line should be "return element.files[0].size <= params.maxsize;" in the event they are uploading a file that is the exact size as your maximum. Otherwise this was very helpful.

Comment: To prevent the required check, just type in "IsValid" : if (file == null) return true;

Answer (score 1):

You can increase request max length for certain urls in web.config:

```
<location path="fileupload">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="10485760" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score -1):

I googled around a bit and came up with the following two URLs which seem to suggest that this problem or exception is best handled at Application's Error event in Global.asax.

1. [Catching 'Maximum request length exceeded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665453/catching-maximum-request-length-exceeded)
2. [How to handle "Maximum request length exceeded" exception](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t97027-how-to-handle-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception.html)