# Is there a way to make jQuery Validation conditional, when used via ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This question has been asked many times here on StackOverflow, but I don't see anything that addresses my need. I want to drive the client side, i.e. jQuery, validation to be conditional by using a server side data annotation.

That is, I am trying to build a generic drop down model where if the user chooses 'Other' from a DropDownList, a coupled text field called `Other` is then mandatory. How can I do this using an attribute on the dropdown model property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Take a look at the [MVC Foolproof framework](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which has many nice additions such as `[RequiredIf]` validation attributes. They also work with client side validation.

If you are interested in the specifics of how to implement this you could take a look at the source code of those attributes. It's quite a lot of work though. You need to have your attributes override the `IClientValidatable` interface and then write custom unobtrusive adapters on the client side.

I wrote an example of such implementation [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10446355/29407). It's not dealing with conditional validation but the technique is exactly the same. You just need to adapt the client side adapter to your needs.

Comment: Darin, you always answer my questions so well. I'm already giving Foolproof a shot, thanks. If it works like I want, I'll event put a bounty on this just to give you points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many RequiredIf implementations around, such as the one below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/10/06/flexible-conditional-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Another option is FluentValidation, which is not an attribute based validation, but very flexible.