# Unable to handle http error 404.13 in mvc 5 app on iis 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I am working on an MVC5 project that allows users to upload files. I already have methods to filter out invalid file extensions (only pictures and pdfs are allowed). However, when I try to upload a large file, regardless of extension, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds
the request content length.
```

The method to upload doesn't even get called, it just goes straight to the error page.

One post I found expressed that I needed to modify my project's `web.config` file, and I did as such:

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="6000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I still get the error, so I also tried adding `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="6000" executionTimeout="3600" />` to `<system.web>`, but that threw this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data 
for the page is invalid.
```

Obviously this line must be for earlier versions of IIS.

I also found another solution that suggested editing the `applicationHost.config` file on my server like the project's `web.config`; this also did nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you actually made the maxAllowedContentLength smaller. The default is 30000000 bytes and you have 6000000 bytes above.

30000000 b = 30 mb

6000000 b = 6 mb

Adding another 0 should do the trick.

Comment: As users will be uploading images and/or pdfs, I want to restrict files to a maximum of 6mb (which is pretty generous for an image, anyway).The 'issue' is if a larger file is submitted, my controller method does not even get hit; the site just goes to the IIS error page.

Comment: The controller won't get called. The framework has fired off those errors protecting the controller.  You will have to trap that in Global.asax.cs application_error

Comment: That is expected because IIS is throwing the error before it process the request/gets to your controller. I would say increase the size in the web.config file so IIS won't throw an error and validate the file size some other way.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445861/validating-for-large-files-upon-upload

Comment: @phillip thanks for that explanation. I figured that was probably why I couldn't do anything.

Comment: @Aaron I am surprised my hours of searching didn't pull this post up...thanks!

Comment: So just for kicks I added an additional zero to the contentLength, allowing ~28MB file. I still get an error page when using a test 5.5MB file, but this time it is an ASP.NET error page not an IIS error page. Weird!