# MVC How to translate this javascript from single getElementById into type="file"

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this JS and it's working perfectly fine, but is it possible to change it from getElementById 'studentPhoto' into input type="file"  instead?

Because I have many

```
<input type="file" id="studentPhoto">
<input type="file" id="studentPhoto">
```

Basically what I want to do is that the below JS will works in every studentPhotoId

```
  document.getElementById('studentPhoto').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

         function checkFile(e) {

             var file_list = e.target.files;

             for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {
                 var sFileName = file.name;
                 var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
                 var iFileSize = file.size;
                 var iConvert = (file.size / 10485760).toFixed(2);

                 if (!(sFileExtension === "pdf" || sFileExtension === "doc" || sFileExtension === "docx") || iFileSize > 10485760) {
                     txt = "File type : " + sFileExtension + "\n\n";
                     txt += "Size: " + iConvert + " MB \n\n";
                     txt += "Please make sure your file is in pdf or doc format and less than 10 MB.\n\n";
                     alert(txt);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI: You can't repeat element with same **id**

Comment: Use classes, not id. Then you can use `document.getElementsByClassName()`, even better, `document.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could switch to a JQuery Selector. The below works on a project of mine with 2 file inputs.

```
function checkFile(e) {

    var file_list = e;

    for (var i = 0; i <= file_list.length; i++) {
       //Do stuff here
    }
}

$("input[type='file']").change(function () {
    checkFile(document.getElementById($(this).attr("id")).files);
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Just a question regarding MVC Core IFormFile, is there a way to add checking FileType or FileSize in the model? like [Required], [FileType] so in my server side the file won't be uploaded

Comment: when you post the HttpPostedFileBase to your server, you should be able to check the ContentLength. Have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445861/validating-for-large-files-upon-upload

Answer (score 1):

Change:

`document.getElementById('studentPhoto')`

To:

`$("input['type=file']")`

Also, you shouldn't use the same `id` on multiple elements, instead use `class`. To select an element by `class`:

`<input type="file" class="studentPhoto">
<input type="file" class="studentPhoto">`

`$('.studentPhoto')`